# What's the encoding used in the output of Linux commands like find, accessed from Python?

Tags: python, unix, encoding, subprocess

Python provides a `subprocess` import that allows fine-grained control of processes, but when I'm creating a process in Unix such as `find`, what's the encoding of the output of these standard Gnu commands?

```
import subprocess
myProcess = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('find ./dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +14'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
outputs = myProcess.communicate()
myStdout = outputs[0].read()
myStderr = outputs[1].read()
print(myStdout.decode('utf-8/ascii')) # ???
```

I'm guessing you can get away with either decoding but officially, how am I supposed to interpret the output of all the standard Unix commands that "output text to the console"?

Comment: Like the `Popen` documentation already tells you, you should avoid it when your use case is supported by one of the higher-level API functions in the library. You are basically reinventing `subprocess.check_call()`; see also the more modern and flexible `subprocess.run()`

Comment: Also, the stuff in `outputs` is already a pair of strings, not the file handles for `stdout` and `stderr` so your attempt mixes two different modes of interacting with `Popen`. This is an excellent example of why you want to avoid `Popen` when you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encoding is not fixed and depends on user's locale. It's usually UTF-8 which is default settings for most of modern distros, but again - user can change that.

You can check current encoding in your local terminal

```bash
$ locale charmap
```

To get that from Python, you can use [locale.getpreferredencoding()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding):

```py
import locale

...

encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
print(myStdout.decode(encoding))
```

Comment: Actually, `subprocess` with `text=True` defaults to using whatever the system's default encoding is, so you don't have to go look it up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on few factors.

The first factor is about the program you are running: it has a fix encoding (or you can set it, e.g. in command line). Usually system programs known about encoding, but many simple and dirt programs may just ignore all encodings.

The second factor: the locale encoding (as known by the system). This encoding can be set by environment variable (e.g. `LANG_ALL`, and `LC_*`), or the system default, which often it is `C` (so ASCII encoding, and English language). Note: default encoding for new users is different (and it just set the environment variable as above in the right place).

But note: the terminal/console must be able to interpret the encoding. If you sent a UTF-8 string to a terminal which can only use 8-bit fonts, you will not see UTF-8 text (although the string may be UTF-8)